# Power BI: Return sum of numerical data for each counterparty and its several currencies between two dates and its variation

Tags: powerbi

I need your help regarding Power BI because I'm quite new with it. I'm struggling to compute and show what I want.

I have imported my table from a database.

[image: Here is the simplified table]

What I want is to compute the sum of the Nominal for each Counterparty and each Currency, BUT it needs to respect the condition: start date <= date in the date table  & end date > date in the date table. At the end, I want to show the result just like the last image, a dynamic table.

Moreover, after computing the sum of the nominal, I need to compute the difference between two dates and the % variation of it.

[image: Here is the date table]

[image: Here is the result I'm looking for with a dynamic table]

On my side, I was able to get the sum I want but the problem is I created columns for each counterparty and currency like 'AZE EUR', 'AZE USD', in the Date table.

BY doing this, I can't create a pie chart that defines the % of EUR or USD owned by AZE and HUB counterparties. So no dynamic chart.

I hope I was clear enough. If not let me know :)
Thank you in advance for all your helps.

NB: if the image can't be seen, let me know.